# How to extract GET parameters with which JS script was called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

First, I will include the script in my HTML.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js?param=value"></script>
```

Second, I want my script to act based on value of param.
I was not able to find any concrete answer to this question.
Is it possible this way?

Something crossed my mind but I didn't tried it because I didn't like the idea so much:
Maybe I could search whole HTML with JQuery, find that string and get the parameter but maybe there is something in JQuery that could help me solve this in more convenient way.

Comment: One solution is to have a server-side language process your JS file.  Like `test.php?param=value`, then add `var param = '<?=$_GET['param']?>';` into your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script id="my-script" type="text/javascript" src="test.js?param=value"></script>

var params = $("#my-script").attr("src").split("?")[1];
```